# Why list as key dictionary, will still show itself as tuple as key dictionary

Tags: python

When I define a dictionary which use list as key

```
collections.defaultdict(list)
```

When I print it out, it shows itself is using tuple as key.

May I know why?

```
import collections

tuple_as_dict_key = collections.defaultdict(tuple)
tuple_as_dict_key['abc', 1, 2] = 999
tuple_as_dict_key['abc', 3, 4] = 999
tuple_as_dict_key['abc', 5, 6] = 888
# defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {('abc', 5, 6): 888, ('abc', 1, 2): 999, ('abc', 3, 4): 999})
print tuple_as_dict_key

list_as_dict_key = collections.defaultdict(list)
list_as_dict_key['abc', 1, 2] = 999
list_as_dict_key['abc', 3, 4] = 999
list_as_dict_key['abc', 5, 6] = 888
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {('abc', 5, 6): 888, ('abc', 1, 2): 999, ('abc', 3, 4): 999})
# Isn't it should be defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {['abc', 5, 6]: 888, ...
print list_as_dict_key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to `defaultdict` is not the type of the key, it is a function that creates default data. Your test cases don't exercise this because you're filling the dict with defined values and not using any defaults. If you were to try to get the value `list_as_dict_key['abc', 7, 8]` it would return an empty list, since that is what you defined as a default value and you never set the value at that index.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice article explaining the answer to why you can't use a list as key [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys).

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding values to your dictionary you're doing it the same way in both cases and they're treated as a tuple. What you're passing to the constructor is the default value for any keys that are not present. Your default value in this case happens to be of type "type", but that has absolutely nothing to do with how other keys are treated.

Comment: Do you mean, I use defaultdict(list), but in runtime, this will treat as defaultdict(tuple)?

Comment: No, what I mean is that it's completely unrelated to that.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary keys can only be [immutable types](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).  Since a list is a mutable type it must be converted to an immutable type such as a tuple to be used as a dictionary key, and this conversion is being done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict` is **not** setting the *key* as a list. It's setting the default *value*.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d1 = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> d1['foo']
[]
>>> d1['foo'] = 37
>>> d1['foo']
37
>>> d1['bar']
[]
>>> d1['bar'].append(37)
>>> d1['bar']
[37]
```

The way that you're getting a tuple as the key type is normal dict behaviour:

```
>>> d2 = dict()
>>> d2[37, 19, 2] = [14, 19]
>>> d2
{(37, 19, 2): [14, 19]}
```

The way Python works with subscripting is that `a` is `a`, `a, b` is a tuple, `a:b` is a slice object. See how it works with a list:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> mylist[4, 5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

It's taken `4, 5` as a tuple. The dict has done the same.